# Red/Black Gambling Game (Expectation)

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, gambling

Source: http://datagenetics.com/blog/october42014/index.html

I have a question about this gambling game where you have a standard deck of 52 cards facing down 26 black and 26 red.

The rules are you draw one card at a time at random.

For each black card you draw, you earn 1 dollar, and for each red card you draw, you lose 1 dollar.

How can I compute the current expected value of the game?

For example in the link above, they offer a formula which I cannot seem to figure out.
For example in the **Four Apples up on top** section computes 1 dollar (1 Black, 2 Red left) and 33 cents (2 Red, 1 Black left) for each branch. How were these computed?

Comment: Usually one specifies that the player has the option of stopping whenever they like.

Comment: I don't believe there is a useful way to do this analytically, but it is not difficult to do via backwards induction.  Just create a state variable that tells you the current mix of red and black for that state.  At each state you can compute the expected value by looking one step further, and then compare it to the value you get by exercising your option.  Obviously, you stop when the exercise value exceeds the value of continuing another turn.

Comment: The values of 2B1R and 1B2R are computed in the previous section **Three cards left**.  They in turn use information from the earlier **One Black and One Red** and **Zero of any one type left** sections